# Is it not OK to reuse a strategy?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question, clarification

For [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55857/print-this-question-%E2%86%93) I wrote a small script to compress a string by replacing substrings that occur a lot with single characters that aren't already in the string (inspired by the ES6 answer), and posted [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55857/print-this-question-%E2%86%93/55936#55936) (which managed to be shorter than the ES6 answer because I replaced more duplicate substrings).

I thought that was a pretty successful strategy so I used the same script to generate a string for [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57053/cardinals-and-ordinals-1-to-100/57060#57060), but that one got a downvote.

Is reusing strategies across multiple questions frowned upon here?

Answer (score 6):

To answer your specific question: Reusing strategies across challenges is perfectly fine. Similar problems require similar approaches.
 It can, on occasions, indicate a bad question (something overly similar has been done before), but not a bad answer.

Try not to draw conclusions from a single downvote. If a downvote comes without any kind of explanation, it is impossible to know for sure why it was cast. There's usually no point in trying to guess. I've received a huge amount of upvotes for posts that didn't really deserve them and downvotes for others of much higher quality.

If I had to guess why your first answer was better received than the second one, I'd say it's because the PHP answer is the shortest one that doesn't use built-in compression, while the JavaScript answer was severely outgolfed by other submissions by the time it was downvoted.

Comment: The only post containing `outgolfed`... by Dennis...